# Send five decimal numbers using UDP in PERL

Tags: perl, sockets, csv, udp

I am new to Perl and Networking part. 
I have to send some bunch of floating point numbers (Which I get from a CSV File) to a hardware using UDP protocol on Perl Platform.

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
#udpclient.pl

use IO::Socket;
use warnings;
use Time::HiRes qw (sleep);


my ($socket,$data);
#my $in_file_name = $ARGV[0];
$in_file_name='C:\Users\Aryan Sinha\Documents\RecordedData.csv';

open(INFILE,"<",$in_file_name) or die "Not able to open test file $!";

$socket = IO::Socket::INET->new (PeerAddr   => '21.22.32.214',
                                 PeerPort  => 5005,
                                 Type      => SOCK_DGRAM,
                                 Proto      => 'udp') or die "ERROR in
+ Socket Creation : $!\n";

while (<INFILE>)
{
    chomp;
    if($. != 1) #skip first line
    {
        $data=$_;  # Data would be in String format

        my @tempData = split(',', $data);

        $socket->send(@tempData);  #This throws an Erro
        sleep(0.25);
    } 

}

$socket->close();
```

@tempData is an Array with 5 Deciaml values which needs to be sent in a single packet. Because these values are from single line .

The hardware can recevie single , double and long double.  I tried to understand pack- unpack functions .. but it doesn't make any sense to me. THis is my 4th day os using perl ..May be I need some more experience.

I also observed that I can transmit the different Hex numbers like this ..

```
$socket->send(\x21\x43\xA2);
```

Do we have anything like this to send floating numbers in a single packet. ?

Any suggestions are highly apreciated.

Comment: It's good you `use warnings;`; I would suggest adding a `use strict;` at the beginning as well. It may give you trouble for a week or so, but will save time & neural cells big time.

Comment: Not sure what format your hardware expects? Comma-separated strings, space-separated strings, binary data?

Answer (score 1):

You can only send bytes, which you provide as a string. Just like any other file handles. Seeing as you already have the numbers serialized, you could simply use the following:

```
while (<INFILE>) {
    next if $. == 1;
    $socket->send($_);
}
```

Why are you using UDP instead of TCP!?!? It's completely inappropriate here because it doesn't guarantee that the packets will arrive, much less in the same order as they were sent.

Comment: Is there any way I can send Numbers instead of String ?  What do u mean by saying "Can send only bytes

Comment: I don't know how else to explain it. The only thing you can write to a file handle (and thus `print` or `send`) is a sequence of bytes. There's nothing special about this one. It's just like every other time you've used `print`. If you want to place some data in a file or send it using `send`, you need to serialize it into bytes (i.e. using CSV, XML, JSON or some packed binary structure) first.

Comment: Thanks ikegami for trying to help me. So , Send($_);  transmits my Data which is numbers in string format to the IP Address. I need to pack the data (Numbers ) first inorder to send it ...  And also to unpack the data at the Receiving End after my UDp Receive block gets the data

Answer (score 1):

**UPD** Ok, it seems I misread the requirements, but just in case someone stumbles upon similar task...

If you're really asking for sending raw floating-point numbers in binary format, `pack` is indeed what you're looking for. Specifically, for sending an array of 5 numbers it should be

```
$socket->send( pack "d[5]", @tempData );
```

Or you may want to send as many numbers as you have, in which case it's `"d*"`.

You may also need to change to `d<*` ([little endian byte order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)) or `d>*` (big endian) depending on device's native byte order. (Hope it's not a pacemaker, so you can find out by experiment which is correct).

Here `d` denotes type ("double"), `<` and `>` denote byte order, and `[5]` and `*` denotes a quantity (`*` = all that you have).

P.S. If the device expects text data, say newline-separated numbers, then `join` should do the trick.

Comment: I used a statement kind of this.  $socket->send( pack "d<*",@ReqData);       Perl interpreter abruplty stops

Comment: @A. Sinha, What do you mean by "abruptly stops"? Killed by a signal? If so, which one? Exits with an error? If so, what error message is printed and what error code is returned?

Comment: Wow! I've never seen `d[5]` before! It's documented to be equivalent to the far more commonly-used `d5`.